# How to loop parents before Child records in a nested collection?

Tags: c#, .net, loops, foreach, while-loop

I have a Nested collection ,  I want to loop through each element in the parent collection before my loop parse to the Nested collection ,

What I have tried so far is ,

```
Private void Loop( PreviewObject  po ) 
{ 
             Console.Writeline(po.Name) ; 

            foreach (PreviewObject child in po.Childrens)
                Loop( child);
}
```

**PreviewObject Class**

```
public class PreviewObject
    {
        private string _name;
        public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }

        private List<PreviewObject> _childrens = new List<PreviewObject>();
        public List<PreviewObject> Childrens
        {
            get { return _childrens; }
            set { _childrens = value; }
        }
    }
```

The problem is the loop goes like this

Assume  X as a collection, And X has element X , which means a Nested collection

X first element is A , 
X Second element is B, 
X's first element's collection's first element is C

IF I loop this as my code , I get the following result ,

A 
C
X

What I want to get is ,

A
B
C

A And B both are element's of parent collections 
So I want to loop through all parent elemetns first, The loop through Element's inside parent element's collections

Can anyone help me to achive this ?

**I tried the following code but it also give me the same result**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections ; 

namespace Breadth_first_traversal
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            list a  = new list();
            a.name = "A";

            list b = new list();
            b.name = "B";
            list c = new list();
            c.name = "C";
            list d = new list();
            d.name = "d";

            list parent = new list();
            parent.name = "Parent";

            parent.Childrens.Add(a);
            parent.Childrens.Add(b);

            a.Childrens.Add(c);
            b.Childrens.Add(d);

            Loop(a);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        private static  void Loop(list  po)
        {
            Queue<list> queue = new Queue<list>();
            queue.Enqueue(po);

            while (queue.Count != 0)
            {
                list  next = queue.Dequeue();
                foreach (list  obj in next.Childrens)
                    queue.Enqueue(obj);

                // Replace with the actual processing you need to do on the item
                Console.WriteLine(next.name);
            }
        }

        public class list
        {
            public string _name;
            public string name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; } }  

            private List<list> childrens = new List<list>(); 
            public List<list> Childrens { get { return childrens ; }  set {childrens  = value ; }   } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

The result I got by the above code is

A
C

but what I must get is

A
B 
C
D

Because First write all element's of parent collection to the console
then write parent's collection elements' collection  to the console

Can someone answer with a nice code example ?

Comment: I don't see any Loop in your code that acccepts 2 arguments

Comment: I edited my question ,  It doesnt' have two parameters now

Comment: ok first of all `Loop(db, child);` should change to `Loop(child);` unless you've got plans you haven't implemented yet

Comment: The question is not a bout Parameters , The question is about the method to looop through all parent elements before loop throught nested collection's elements

Comment: just an error i spotted earlier, that's why i put it in the comments.

Comment: In your second version of the code, you should be calling Loop(parent), not Loop(a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a breadth-first traversal. You can achieve it by maintaining a Queue of nodes to visit. Add the root of your collection to the Queue. Now, start pulling items from the Queue. As you get each item, do whatever processing you want on it, then add all of its children to the end of the queue. Continue pulling nodes from the Queue and processing them until the Queue is empty.

EDIT: Sample code

```
private void Loop(PreviewObject po)
{
    Queue<PreviewObject> queue = new Queue<PreviewObject>();
    queue.Enqueue(po);

    while(queue.Count != 0)
    {
        PreviewObject next = queue.Dequeue();
        foreach(PreviewObject obj in next.Childrens)
            queue.Enqueue(obj);

        // Replace with the actual processing you need to do on the item
        Console.WriteLine(next.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think breadth-first "search" is a more common name for this approach. Wikipedia explains it nicely and has some pseudo code
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search

Comment: @noggin182 Breadth-first search is a subset of breadth-first traversal. While it may be a more common term, it is not, in this case, accurate.

Comment: @Jon, sorry my comment came across wrong. It's not the correct term for what he wants to do, but he would likely get more help searching google for the incorrect term.

Comment: This helped me , Thank you friend , Your code sample was very helpful :) , And I marked your answer as the answer , and Have already upvoted it : )